# React Native - Infinite Scroll ListView

Tags: android, ios, listview, react-native

I am trying to implement an infinite scroll ListView in React Native. This works by detecting when the listview reaches the bottom of its content length and firing another API. When a response is received, the new data is appended to the original data (this is done in my Flux store). However in my component, I update the dataSource via:

```
setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(Store.getLatestData())
})
```

The problem I seem to be having is everytime this happens, the ListView is refreshed and loses its scroll position (it returns to the top). How do I go about adding the new data without losing the current position?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I am trying to save the scroll offset before adding the new data then scroll to the origin offset after adding data.
I am trying to do this by:

```
this._listView.getScrollResponder().scrollTo(offset, 0);
```

where this._listView is a refs to the ListView component. However, this._listView always seems to be null whenever I access it. My guess is that the reference  to the listview is null for a split second during rerendering?

**UPDATE 2**

For more information:

My getInitialState is:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
        sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => true
    });
    return {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(LeaderboardsStore.getLeaderboard()),
        //some other state too
    }
```

Once I have detected the user has scrolled to the bottom, I set off an API call via the fetch API which returns the new data and is appended to the original array via concat. The store that holds the array (a flux store) emits a change event.

In my onStoreChange callback I reassign the dataSource as follows:

```
setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(Store.getLatestData())
})
```

which updates my ListView as expected (with the unwanted change in scroll position).

My Render method looks like (for simplicity):

```
render:function() {
    return (
        <ListView 
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this._renderRow}
            ref={(component) => {this._listView = component;}}
         />
    );
}
```

I tried changing my onStoreChange callback to:

```
onStoreChangeCallback: function() {
    this._scrollOffset = this._listView.scrollProperties.offset;
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(Store.getLatestData())
    }, function() {
        if (this._scrollOffset !== undefined) {
            this._listView.getScrollResponder().scroll(offset, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

however, this._listView seems to be null at the getScrollResponder line :(

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to know the issue without seeing more code, however, I am assuming that React Native doesn't understand that you have merged items to the original list. Make sure you use `concat` to join the items:

`incidents = _.uniq(incidents.concat(payload.action.response), "id")`
`IncidentsStore.emitChange(RECEIVED_EVENT)`

In this example I use concat and then lodash to make sure I don't have doubles by accident.

In addition, your `getLatestData` should return a copy of the original items (`slice(0)` is an easy way to do it) like this:

```
getIncidents: (state) ->
  dataSource: state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(incidents.slice(0))
  loaded: true
```

Hope that helps, let me know if you have questions.

**UPDATE**

You don't need to save the position. Your list view should look like this:

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={this.renderRow}
  style={styles.listView}
  onEndReachedThreshold=1200
  onEndReached={this.fetchMoreLeaders}
/>
```

In my component I add the following listener:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.pageNumber = 0;
  IncidentsStore.addLeadersReceivedListener(this.updateList);
  return this.fetchMoreLeaders();
},

fetchMoreLeaders: function() {
  return LeadersActions.fetchLeaders(this.pageNumber += 1);
},

updateList: function() {
  return this.setState(LeadersStore.getLeaders(this.state));
},
```

My store will return something like this:

```
getLeaders: function(state) {
  return {
    dataSource: state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(leaders.slice(0)),
    loaded: true
  };
},
```

When the new data comes in I was the concat I wrote earlier with the _.uniq

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry I should have clarified earlier. I am appending the new data using concat and I can see that it works as I can see the new additional results in the listview. The problem is that everytime I scroll to the bottom and new data is appended, the listview refreshes to the top of the screen again. I would like it to stay at the same offset as before appending new data.

Comment: What is happens in this.fetchMoreLeaders? Does an API call get set off, and then once the response is returned and concatenated to the original array, how is the ListView dataSource updated?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you were able to resolve this but I was having the same problem and I am adding what worked well for me.

First of all set the data in state or you can use `getInitialState`

```
state = {
    loading: true,
    currentPage: 1,
    data: {
      collection: []
    }
  }
```

Then fetch the required data in `componentDidMount`, here `user` is my service which is simply a wrapper to make api calls.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({loading: true}, ()=>{
        user.artists().then((data)=>{
          const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
          const dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(data.collection);
          this.setState({
            data,
            dataSource,
            loading: false
          });
          console.log(data.last_page);
        }).catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err);
        }).done();
      });
  }
```

This is how I am rendering my `ListView`

```
renderPartial(datas) {
    if (datas.length === 0) {
      return <View/>;
    }
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    const dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(datas);
    return (
      <ListView
        enableEmptySections={true}
        dataSource={dataSource}
        onEndReached={()=>this.loadOtherPage()}
        onEndReachedThreshold={400}
        renderRow={(rowData) => this.renderContent(rowData)}
      />
    );
  }
```

`onEndReached` triggers the `this.loadOtherPage` function which goes like this, here you can see that I just push the new result in  data
`data.collection.push(item);`
This way new data is concatenated with the existing one and the view port stays at the current position instead of going back to the top.

```
loadOtherPage() {
    if (this.state.currentPage !== this.state.data.last_page && !this.state.loading) {
      this.setState({currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1, loading: true}, ()=>{
        user.artists({page: this.state.currentPage})
          .then((response)=>{
            const data = this.state.data;
            response.collection.map((item)=>{
              data.collection.push(item);
            });
            this.setState({
              data,
              loading: false});
          }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
    } else {
      console.log('max page reached or it is still loading');
    }
  }
```

I hope this helps someone.